# Quotation marks not working - entries template

Tags: ee2

When a blog post has quotes or apostrophes in it *“like this”* or when *it’s* like *‘this,’* the punctuation is replaced with characters like â€™s or â€™s. This is only in the blog/entry template. Everything works fine in the blog/index template.

Any ideas why? Both templates have the following code in the header:

`meta charset="utf-8"`

And the site language is English.

Here is the code for the blog/entry template:

http://shorttext.com/xVwZkP

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I haven’t found much documentation on this. Help?

Comment: What character encoding is your database/table set to? My guess is there's a mismatch between your database and your document.

Comment: Admin > Channel Administration > Channel (Blog) > XML Language > English

That is also the default language on the General Configuration page.

Comment: Do you have access to a tool like phpmyadmin or mysql on the command line where you can check the encodings for the database itself?

Comment: We don't. Is there any way we can check using the EE web interface?

Answer (score 1):

What is the encoding of the blog/entry template? Open it on a code editor and make sure it's a UTF-8 no BOM file.

If you don't have access to the files by FTP, try... Well, I don't know if this will work. Let's try.

- [Synchronize all files](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/synchronize_templates.html);
- [Set *Allow templates as files* to **no**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html);
- [go to edit the template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/templates.html) blog/entry;
- [cut its content from the editor](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/edit_template.html);
- paste on a code editor program;
- convert its encoding to UTf-8 without BOM;
- cut the content from the editor;
- paste it back on the template editor of the CP.

Comment: Is there a way I can check that in the web editor? The way our site is set up, we don't have FTP access.

Comment: Answer updated.